# EWS busytime attendee

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am doing a query for AttendeeAvailability via EWS Managed API 2.1.

```
var freeBusyResults = service.GetUserAvailability(
    attendees, 
    time,
    AvailabilityData.FreeBusy,
    new AvailabilityOptions()
);
foreach (AttendeeAvailability avail in freeBusyResults.AttendeesAvailability) {
    foreach (var ce in avail.CalendarEvents) { 
        if(ce.StartTime < time.EndTime || ce.EndTime > time.StartTime) 
            list.Add(avail.Attendee); //Attendee has conflicting entry.
    }
}
```

This code won't work, because I did not find a property Attendee or any similar property in AttendeeAvailability, that would contain which attendee the result is for. Is there any? If not, how do I know which attendee(s) have a conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results don't contain any of that detail (you can enabled tracing and have a look at the results). The way to work it out is the FreeBusy results in AttendeesAvailability collection that is returned is in the order you submitted them in the attendees collection . So you just need to put some code to match the results eg

```
        Int32 AtnCnt = 0;
        foreach (AttendeeAvailability avail in freeBusyResults.AttendeesAvailability)
        {
            AttendeeInfo CurrentAttendee = attendees[AtnCnt];               
            foreach (var ce in avail.CalendarEvents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(CurrentAttendee.SmtpAddress);
            }
            AtnCnt++;
        }
```

Cheers
Glen